# why body is defined in window object

Tags: javascript, dom

I was just playing around in the console, and noticed that if I type:

`body` it returns `<body>...</body>`

This is obviously the same as `window.body`, which therefore also returned `<body>...</body>`

Then `document.body` also returns `<body>...</body>` as expected, as the body is part of the `document` object, and as far as I was aware, not the `window` object.

For this reason I expected `window.body` to return undefined.

Then I checked `window.head` which returned `undefined`.

This is the result I expected to happen with `window.body`

Finally, `document.head` returned `<head>...</head>` as expected.

Can anyone explain where `window.body` comes from? A search on google, and stackoverflow couldn't answer this one for me.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` for `window.body` in Chrome. Please specify which browser you're using.

Comment: I'm also getting `undefined` on Firefox. Could be an artifact of your browser or of the page you have loaded.

Comment: Did you do a `body = document.body` earlier in the console? That's where `window.body` comes to life.

Comment: ...or if the HTML happens to have `<body id="body">`.

Comment: wow! very strange. check if you run it on this page? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-q1z8BPFItw When I opened a new tab it showed `undefined`

Comment: that's it -- the page has `<body id=body>`

Comment: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: Never saw this before, thanks @Juhana

Answer (score 0):

The `window.body` element is not the same as the `document.body` element unless some javascript on the page has already assigned that as a helper method.

As mentioned in the comments on your question, the default would be `undefined` for `window.body` (and hence simply `body`).

Here are 3 screenshots from Chrome, Safari and Firefox consoles showing what the google homepage (google.co.uk in this case) sets as the result of `window.body` compared with `document.body`. Clearly not the same as `document.body`, therefore you can tell they've done that themselves for a particular reason (as had the page you're looking at possibly):

### Chrome

[image]

### Safari

[image]

### Firefox

[image]

Hope that helps.